# UDP listener with task-based asynchronous pattern

Tags: c#, multithreading, io, task-parallel-library, async-await

I am messing around with a UDP listener and the TAP.

I have a class that is responsible for listening for incoming UDP and that can be started and stopped.
The Start() method simply calls the following method

```
    private async void Listen()
    {
        var resp = await _udpClient.ReceiveAsync().ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);

        var eventHandler = PacketReceived;
        if (eventHandler != null)
            eventHandler(this, new UdpPacketReceivedEventArgs(resp));

        if (_running)
            Listen();
    }
```

Is this correct? I am a bit worried that I might exhaust the thread pool, because the thread is being kept alive by spawning a new Listen() call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this correct? I am a bit worried that I might exhaust the thread pool, because the thread is being kept alive by spawning a new Listen() call.

Yes, it's *totally* correct, this operation is not CPU bound, it's IO bound. So, there are no threads in thread pool at all that are blocked waiting for the operation to complete.

There is a thread waiting for network requests to complete, but it is shared between all network requests (like UI thread). It’s called the  IO completion port thread on Windows. When the network request completes, an interrupt handler in the operating system adds a job to a queue for the IO completion port. To perform 1000 network requests, the requests are all started, and as the responses arrive, they are processed in turn by the single IO completion port.

Comment: IO completion ports don't have threads "waiting" for IO to complete.  A thread "waiting" is a thread that is in use.  Overlapped IO has its own pool of threads and will use one of these threads when the IO completes.

Comment: @PeterRitchie: thanks for your comment, could you explain more on this stuff, seems I don't have deep understanding. Or even you can post another more corrective answer for this question?

Comment: Thanks for answering. At least the thread running the task is alive? Why does it simply die, when it is told to run Listen() again?

Comment: @lejon: thread is running under thread pool, so it will be utilized for another task, it will die when being idle in amount of time

Comment: @CuongLe: I see. So what you're saying is that the completion port activates a thread off the threadpool, with a pointer to the function that should handle the callback, when the completion port (somehow) receives instructions to do so?